# "Up to" vs "up to it"

Tags: idioms

What does the phrase *up to* mean in the following?

> That sketchy character is *up to* something.
>
> That sneak is *up to* no good.

How does that differ from *up to it* in the following?

> I'm sick, but if I'm *up to it* I may do the dishes.

Or this:

> I feel like I'm *up to* my ears, trying to learn all these English idioms.

Are there other uses of this phrase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are all established meanings/idioms for "up to".  The first two sentences use "up to" with the meaning, "devising or scheming; occupied with".  The next sentence with "up to it" has the meaning "having adequate powers or ability for; capable of; equal to".  The final sentence has the meaning "as far as or approaching (a certain part, degree, point, etc.)".

I got these from [this dictionary.com entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/up), which also has examples of many other uses.

Answer (score 2):

All of these are examples of "be up to" rather than "up to" alone. "Be up to" is something called a phrasal verb, and it has two meanings. See Kosmonaut's answer for definitions.