# What does "What are you up to?" mean?

Tags: idioms

I overheard my manager asking "What are you up to?"

What does that idiom mean? Is it an informal/negative way of asking??

Comment: It's just an informal way of asking "What are you doing right now". See http://esl.about.com/library/lessons/blphrasalbuild.htm

Comment: An excellent example of a sentence that's awkward to not end with a preposition: "up to what are you?"

Comment: @Seamus: True, but it's not like you'd be using this construction in a formal setting.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2186/up-to-vs-up-to-it/2188#2188).

Comment: @Seamus, unless you're Yoda, in which case that's perfectly natural.

Comment: @BenLee The rules of grammar Yoda does not adhere to.

Comment: @Seamus: I would phrase it "To what are you up," which is still very awkward.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"What are you up to?" means

> "What have you been doing lately?".

If you add an adverb to the end of the phrase, for instance,

> "What are you up to tonight?" *or* "What
>   are you up to this summer?"

it can be interpreted as

> "What are you planning to do tonight?"
>   *or* "What are you planning to do this
>   summer?".

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. Makes things just slightly clearer in my view, good answer otherwise.

Comment: @Noldorin: No problem. Thanks for improving my answer.

Comment: Can also mean "What's your scheme?" as when the boss comes in after hours to find you hauling cement bags into the office.

Comment: There is no definition of "be up to" on Merriam-Webster site. Is it not used in American English? I found it only in Cambridge dictionary.

Answer (score 10):

Can I also add that the intention should be determined by the tone the person uses when asking. If they are asking it in a light hearted open way, they genuinely want to know what you are doing (at the moment or a later point in time).

If there appears to be suspicion in their tone, they may be implying that you are "up to" something you shouldn't be and should stop.

A common phrase is "are you up to mischief?” which means "are doing something naughty, you shouldn't be"?

Comment: I think this distinction is important and salient and I'm really surprised the checkmark went to answer that didn't even mention this.

Comment: +1 for first two paragraphs, but no one ever says "are you up to mischief?"

Answer (score 2):

"What are you up to?"

```
                = "What do you intend to do?" 

                = "What are you willing to do?"
```

And about it being formal or not, *as far as I know*, it is more friendly than formal.

Answer (score 1):

It means, 'What are you doing?' and is similar to the phrase, 'He's up to something'. Yes, it is generally informal.

Comment: I'd add that if you say that someone is "up to something", it generally insinuates that they're "up to no good", or some kind of mischief...

Comment: Indeed, "What are _you_ up to?" might have this sense - it depends on the tone. But without the emphasis, I don't think there will usually be any negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of a **phrasal verb** -- see [Why do we use 'up' as adverbs for verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/why-do-we-use-up-as-adverbs-for-verbs) for more information.