# explain the idiom

Tags: grammar, idioms

I am the novice English learner.
Please explain me the idiom "What are you up to" I've already google it. But i still want you people to explain this with examples.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Samridhi, you can find an aswer here:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/what-does-what-are-you-up-to-mean. You may also like to see how this site works:http://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Good.. Thanks for the help.I am satisfied with the answers.